# Variable inside a spinbox widget to display in the LCD widget at a click of the pushbutton widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

What should I do when I want the variable inside a spinbox widget to display in the LCD widget at a click of the pushbutton widget?

Code form converting .ui to .py. Now I don't know what else to do. please edit as you see fit. :-)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\CpE-18\Desktop\mk2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 250, 51, 31))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 110, 141, 101))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 320, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Post the code you have working so far. Them someone might be able to look at it and provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following:

- Create a function that is called when the button is pressed, for this the clicked signal is used.
- Obtain the value of the QSpinBox using the value() method.
- Set the value in the QLCDNumber through the display() method.

```py
# ...

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # ...

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        self.lcdNumber.display(self.spinBox.value())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```